# How to display results in order?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to design a form for a quiz. I have 15 questions in the database. I want to display 10 question to the user with shuffling, but I am having difficulty displaying the questions sequentially.

My PHP code is:

```
<form action="includes/backend_quiz.php" method="post">
    <?php
        $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM quiz order by rand() LIMIT 10") or die("Could not retrieve data: " .mysqli_error($conn));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){           
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){               
                    extract($row);  

                    ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
                        <h4><?php echo $id ?>.&nbsp  <?php echo $quation; ?></h4><br />

                        <input type="radio" name="response" value="a" /> <?php echo $opt1;?><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="response" value="b" /> <?php echo $opt2;?><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="response" value="c" /> <?php echo $opt3;?><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="response" value="d" /> <?php echo $opt4;?><br />
                        <br />
                    <?php

            }
        }       
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="ans" value="Finish"/>
</form>
```

Output:

[image]

So, how do I display the questions sequentially like Q1, Q2, Q3, etc.?

Comment: you need to use ajax,

Comment: What do you mean by _set question sequentially_? If you want to order the questions by a field in the database table you can sort them already when querying: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM quiz order by rand() LIMIT 10) ORDER BY 'Id';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<form action="includes/backend_quiz.php" method="post">
<?php
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM quiz order by rand() LIMIT 10") or die("Could not retrieve data: " .mysqli_error($conn));
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            $number = 0;           
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){               
                extract($row);  
                $number++;
                ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
                    <h4><?php echo $number?>.&nbsp  <?php echo $quation; ?></h4><br />

                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="a" /> <?php echo $opt1;?><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="b" /> <?php echo $opt2;?><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="c" /> <?php echo $opt3;?><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="d" /> <?php echo $opt4;?><br />
                    <br />
                <?php

        }
    }       
?>
<input type="submit" name="ans" value="Finish"/>
```

Comment: how to submit answer in database if u have solution please tell me